# Poisson Random Variable : Phone Calls

Tags: probability, solution-verification, poisson-distribution

I am attempting the following problem:

**Question**: A receptionist at a corporate company receives:

- outside calls at a rate of 3 calls in any 10 minute time frame.
- inside calls at a rate of 4 calls in any 10 minute time frame.

Compute the probability of receiving 2 or more calls in any 2 minute time frame. The calls arrive independently and at random.

---

**Attempt**:

- Calculate $\lambda=\frac{7}{10}*{2}=\frac{7}{5}=1.4$

\begin{align}
P(X \geq 2) &= 1-P(X<2)\\ \nonumber &=1-P(X=1)-P(X=0)\\ \nonumber &= 1-\frac{e^{-1.4}1.4^{1}}{1!}-\frac{e^{-1.4}1.4^{0}}{0!}
\\ \nonumber &= 0.40816...
\end{align}

---

Comment: The mass function is $e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$. *Note the negative exponent*. Further you should be summing an infinite series not a finite sum.

Comment: though to get a finite sum you can find the probability of not getting exactly $1$ or fewer calls

Comment: @NapD.Lover thank you for pointing that out, I have made those edits.

Comment: @Henry Thank you, I realized that I misinterpreted the problem and solved for "no more than 2 calls" instead of "2 or more calls". I have made edits to my post.